# Rename filename.ext.crswap to filename.ext rather than copying

Tags: native-file-system-api-js

When performing this sequence

- Obtain a handle to a new file via `window.showSaveFilePicker`, say `filename.ext`
- Obtain a writeable file stream from the handle
- Write some content into the file using the stream
- `close` the stream to signal completion

the File System API writes to `filename.ext.crswap` and on `close` copies `filename.ext.crswap` to `filename.ext`

Is there a reason that `filename.ext.crswap` is not rather renamed to `filename.ext`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is to avoid partial writes:

*"User agents try to ensure that no partial writes happen, i.e. the file represented by `fileHandle` will either contain its old contents or it will contain whatever data was written through stream up until the stream has been closed."*—[Spec](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/#:%7E:text=User%20agents%20try%20to%20ensure%20that%20no%20partial%20writes%20happen%2C%20i.e.%20the%20file%20represented%20by%20fileHandle%20will%20either%20contains%20its%20old%20contents%20or%20it%20will%20contain%20whatever%20data%20was%20written%20through%20stream%20up%20until%20the%20stream%20has%20been%20closed.).

Comment: But surely renaming `filename.ext.crswap`  to `filename.ext` instead of copying would not violate this intent?

Comment: Not the implementer of the feature, but I seem to recall it has to do with the code having to work for both writing to new files and appending to existing files.